# Automatically clicking on a link based on different column's text

Tags: html, imacros

Using iMacros, I want to click on a link in the same row as another column's text. How would I do this?

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>Link</td>
       <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. If you give us more info we can give you better answer.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=HREF:Link
```